# Can I pass a function call as a parameter to another function? Python

Tags: python

Let's assume that I am making a function call and pass its return value as a parameter to another function. Should I do it like this:

```
value = self.__myFunction(self.parent.connectToVars.getCertainValue())
```

Or like this?

```
certainValue = self.parent.connectToVars.getCertainValue()
value = self.__myFunction(certainValue)
```

Personally, I tend to use the first choice as it is only 1 line of code and I am not making any local variables that could potentially distract me, but I am concerned if there could be a runtime error or it is just a bad practice.

Comment: If you are not going to do anything further with `certainValue` beyond passing it to another function, then there is no need to use you second approach at all.  It is neither bad practice nor going to cause some kind of runtime error

Comment: It's fine. You might want to introduce intermediate variables if the line starts getting too long or too nested for easy human readability, but it's not going to break anything.

Comment: If an exception was raised during the inner function call, you would be able to catch it anyway. So my preference goes to option 1.

Comment: Option 2 is also useful if it's not obvious what the value represents because you're giving it a name which explains that. And if you're using a tool like Sentry then the value of the local variable can show up in the error log if the second line raises an error. If the first version raises an error it should be clear from the traceback which function went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option is perfectly fine, just keep in mind that this way, the return value of the inner function is not accessible later. Therefore, if the inner function is time-costly an You want to use it's return value multiple times, it is better to save it in temporary variable so You don't have to compute it every time from the beginning.

**edit:**

As Alex mentioned it's usually a bad practice to needlessly compute something multiple times. So summarizing, if You will use a return value of a function multiple times use a temp variable for it, otherwise You can use the first option.

Comment: Even if the calculation is not costly, the logic there is complicated enough that it should not be repeated.